# Create Wordpress templates based on another (parent) template

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm attempting to create a new page template, *Custom Page*, based on the basic *Page* template.

What I'd like to do in my *Custom Page* template is create some HTML, define where to add it into the basic *Page* template, then just include the basic *Page* template.

What I **don't** want to do is copy and paste the contents of the *Page* template into my *Custom Page* template, then just modify it. Why? Because it helps with maintainability - I want to be able to modify the basic *Page* template in the future, and have any changes automatically apply to my *Custom Page* template as well.

Here's an example of what I've got so far in my *Custom Page* template:

```
<?php
    /* Template Name: Custom Page */
    // this template is based on the page template, with some additional content.
    // We'll use ob_start to get the content, and assign it to the_content, by wrapping it in a function, then include the page template
    function customPageExtraContent($content){
        ob_start();
?>
        <!-- Custom content goes here -->
        <div>
            <form>
                <label for="exampleInput">Example Input</label>
                <input type="text" name="exampleInput "id="exampleInput">
            </form>
        </div>
        <!--  Custom content ends here -->
<?php
        // collect the html
        $html = ob_get_clean();
        $content .= $html;
        return $content;
    }

    // add the html to the_content
    add_filter( 'the_content', 'customPageExtraContent', 20); // 20 priority runs after other filters so the content is appended.

    // include page
    get_template_part('page');

?>
```

This works, and adds the above html onto the_content.

What I'd like to know is:

1. **Is this actually a good way of achieving what I'm trying to do?**
2. **If so, is there a way of abstracting the customPageExtraContent function, so I can use it across multiple custom page templates**

Currently if I create another page template, I'll have to define a new function for that one e.g.

```
function customPageExtraContent2($content){
    ...
}
```

What I'd like to do is have a generic function, which I pass the extra html to for this particular template.

So I could have in my functions file a function like

```
function customPageExtraContent($content, $extraHTML){
    return $content.$extraHTML;
}
```

And then in any of my custom templates I can just call this function.

My problem with doing this? I can't work out how to pass arguments to my callback function... e.g I'd like to be able to do this in my custom template

```
add_filter('the_content', customPageExtraContent($content, $extraHTML), 20);
```

Anyone who knows what I'm babbling on about offer any suggestions?

Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Don't create a page template if you want the current page template to be called - you'd have to set *which* template you want to call. Use `template parts` to create part of the template - and then call it under an `if/while` statement.

Source:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/

Comment: I *want* to be able to set the template in the CMS.

Comment: If I just include the template part I'd need to use a conditional such as

`if(is_page_template'CustomPageTemplateName')){
    get_template_part('extra');
}`

I could do that on my basic page template. To select this template in the admin I could create a custom template with nothing in it other than the name...

But that just seems backwards.

Comment: Alright I'm completely lost in what you're actually asking. In layman's terms?

Comment: Haha sorry!

I want a user in the CMS to be able to select a custom page template. This custom page template is the same as the basic page template **except** for some additional content - e.g. a contact form. This gives the user the power to select whether any given page uses the basic page template, or a basic page with a contact form added on, for example. So basically I want a way of defining my custom page template and within it saying "Use the basic page template, but insert X extra html in Y location". Make sense?

Comment: I see - so you just want custom fields? Look at http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/ - This way you can add a custom field to whichever template that's been chosen. E.g. add an image, form etc. I still believe using the get_template_part would be fine in this situation and choosing how it's called.

Comment: I'm actually already using ACF for a bunch of content. Maybe my example was quite simple, but imagine my basic page has 8 included custom field groups, and my custom template has 4 extra custom field groups, and a bunch of other custom functionality beside, which I don't want to include with my basic page template, I want the user to easily be able to just enable all this extra stuff by just switching templates - I don't want it appearing as an option on every page.